# Wordpress: Email Linking Issue

Tags: wordpress, email

I have got quite a weird issue, on my website.
On the top right, there is an email address and a phone number.
The email address is set in the general settings in the dashboard.

The problem, is that when I rollover the email address, only the tip of the "m" in .com becomes active. It is as if there is an invisible object lying above the email address.
What I need, is for the whole email address to be active, when the user rolls over.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element

```
<header class="big box unit whole">
```

Has it's z-index set to 770. You should reduce this, or increase the z-index to 771 on the

```
<div class="header-info-block">
```

element.

You'll need to do some digging into the sites css / theme files to do this.

Comment: Thanks - I fixed it, your answer provided the clue I needed. Thank You.